Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 (flutter doctor, flutter clean cannot solve)
[Fatal Error] x86_debug-1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.
Required by:
project :app
> Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.
> Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4/x86_debug-1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.
Required by:
project :app > project :shared_preferences_android
> Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.
> Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I tried to solve the error by running flutter clean, flutter upgrade, flutter doctor but it doesn't work. May I know how can I solve the problem?

Try with these commands.
flutter clean
gradlew cleanBuildCache
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
flutter upgrade

